# Declare empty es6 Set inside object literal

Tags: javascript, set, ecmascript-6

I have a JavaScript object:

```
 let component = {
                id: comp.id,
                name: comp.name,
                attributes: {
                    initial: [
                    ],
                    final: [
                    ]
                }
            };
```

To prevent duplication in `initial` and `final` properties I want to use `Set` instead of `array`, but how do we declare `Set` without `new` operator inside object literal? I want to avoid doing the following if possible:

```
component.attributes.initial = new Set();

component.attributes.final = new Set();
```

Comment: Why do you think you have to assign the property afterwards if you use `new Set`?

Comment: @FelixKling I feel so dumb asking this question instead of giving it a try first

Comment: *but how do we declare Set without `new` operator inside object literal, I want to avoid doing following if possible* Why?

Comment: @torazaburo to keep the code cleaner, why to declare it outside if it can be done inline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with declaring an empty set inside the object literal:

```
let component = {
     id: comp.id,
     name: comp.name,
     attributes: {
         initial: new Set(),
         final: new Set()
     }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    attributes: {
                    initial: new Set([]),
                    final: new Set([])
                }
```

Comment: Aren't the `[]` inside `new Set([])` redundant?

Comment: The intention was to show that you can specify initial set of values for the set in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *any* expression as value of a property in an object literal, which includes `new Set`:

```
{
   initial: new Set(),
   final: new Set(),
}
```